# How to get the object from within an imported member function?

Tags: python, ctypes, member

In the code sample below, I'd like to be able to used the `dll` object within the helper function.

```
def HelperFunc():
    # How to use dll here?
    pass

def LoadMyDLL():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL( "libmydll.so" )
    dll.HelperFunction = HelperFunction
    return dll

dll = LoadMyDLL()
dll.HelperFunc()
```

I can obviously pass it as a parameter to `HelperFunc`, but is I'm importing this function, faking it is included into the dll, it wouldn't be clean to call `dll.HelperFunc(dll)` with the `dll` repetition.

I could also store the `dll` object into a global variable. I'd then need to add a protection to avoid loading the dll twice, keeping a single dll loaded.

But is there a way to get `dll` from within `HelperFunc`, or having it passed silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one thing people often forget (or never learn) is that functions have attributes as well and they're entirely mutable. So you could do:

```
def LoadMyDLL():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL("libmydll.so")
    dll.HelperFunction = HelperFunction
    dll.HelperFunction.dll = dll
    return dll
```

But this produces a problem: `dll.HelperFunction.dll is HelperFunction.dll`. So whatever your last call to `LoadMyDLL` is, will be the `CDLL` object that is attached to `HelperFunction`. If you are not using HelperFunction outside of the context of `dll.HelperFunction()` then I suggest you do the following: Don't make `HelperFunc` an attribute of `dll`, just call `HelperFunction(dll)` where needed. If you want it to modify `dll` since Python is pass-by-reference, it will do so. If you don't believe me and want me to post example code, I'll be happy to edit this with an illustration.

**Disclaimer** In general what you seem to be doing doesn't look right at all to me. If you want to do something like this, I would suggest making a class that stores the `CDLL` object as `self.dll` and making `HelperFunction` a method on the class. Then you can access `self.dll` from that method. Of course, the design is your decision and I can't see the rest of the code, but the latter just seems more natural to me (and my guess would be, to plenty of others as well).

**Edit** Just due to the discussion below, I'd like to give an idea as to how I might think of constructing the class I suggested (even though the above was accepted as is).

```
class DLLHelper(object):
    def __init__(self, static_object=None, helper_function=None):
        self.dll = ctypes.CDLL(static_object or "libmydll.so")

    def HelperFunction(self):
        # do stuff with self.dll

    def OtherRelatedFunction(self):
        # do stuff with self.dll and self.HelperFunction


dll = DLLHelper()
dll.HelperFunction()
```

Comment: @glglgl I don't see him saying he'll only ever call it once. Like I said, if he calls it several times then he will run into the problem I mentioned. And if he abstracts the logic to load arbitrary libraries then he'll run into serious issues.

Comment: I also thought about doing as you explained in your disclaimer. However, when calling any function of the dll, user will have to call `dll.dll.functionToCall()`, and more than ugly, it's not convenient.

Comment: If you wrap the dll, just make a method that makes the call for them. Why would they need to access the dll directly? That's the purpose of a class.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid globals you can use a closure or an object with a static method to save and reuse dll.

```
def LoadMyDLL(dll = ctypes.CDLL( "libmydll.so" )):
    def closure():
        return dll
    return closure

dll = LoadMyDLL()()
```

and the same for the helper func to use the dll binding:

```
def HelperFunc():
    dll = LoadMyDLL()()
    # and use the dll
```

**UPDATE**

The above answer worked, not because of the closure, but because of the default keyword argument dll in the global function LoadMyDLL.

This default keyword argument (dll = ...) is initialized once, when the function LoadMyDLL is defined as a global function.
This means there is a very easy solution :

```
def LoadMyDLL(dll = ctypes.CDLL( "libmydll.so" )):
    return dll

dll = LoadMyDLL() # get the dll, which has already been initialized
```

and in the helper function :

```
def HelperFunc():
    dll = LoadMyDLL() # get the dll again
    # and use the same dll
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def HelperFunc():
    HelperFunc.dll.OtherFunction()

def LoadMyDLL():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL( "libmydll.so" )
    HelperFunction.dll = dll
    dll.HelperFunction = HelperFunc
    return dll

dll = LoadMyDLL()
dll.HelperFunc()
```

would be a way to do it. There surely are better ways, however...

Comment: There are problems with this. See my answer please.